# HTTPS Ajax request failure when SSL Certificate changed

Tags: ajax, extjs, ssl, extjs4.2

In our system we have a case, when SSL certificate changed in backend, and as you can imagine Ajax requests are not working after that.

```
 Ext.Ajax.request({
     url : 'myaction',
     method : 'POST',
     success : function(response, options) {
         // some code here
     },
     failure : function(response, options) {
         // when SSL changed request failed
     }
 });
```

In response we have no additional data to understand if the problem is because of SSL change.

What I want to do?
 If there will is any option to understand if failure because of SSL changing I will be able to show some message and then just reload the page to allow user accept new one.

Comment: have you tried to restart web server? I guess, the server doesn't load the new SSL.

Comment: Also, are there any virus scanner available in your client? Because, some virus scanners also scan SSL certificates.

Comment: There is no some unusual case. It is the process of setup/configuring product, during that you can ask to get certificate from another instance.

Comment: Is this with a server certificate? If so, "As you can imagine Ajax requests are not working after that" I actually don't understand why that would be, if the new certificate is valid, unless the server is buggy.